# Using a Variable in REQUESTS in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I've got an API request to make that involves passing some variables from user input and a config file to a filter expression contained in a dictionary.

The API uses hashes in its structure to wrap stings by default, although I can specify another string wrapping indicator if need be via a separate request. As is, what I need to do is below, basically.

I can't figure out the syntax to get those strings to populate the values between the wrapper # signs. Lots of questions about this, but none addressing the basic syntax without additional functionality, as far as I can tell.

```
import config
import requests

var1 = **the result of user input, a string**
var2 = **a value from a config file, also a string**

url = (config.api_url)
payload = {
'key':config.api_key,
'Operation':'GetEntities',
'Entity':'my_entity',
'Attributes':'my_attribute1,my_attribute2',
'Filter':'api_var1<eq>#var1# AND api_var2<eq>#var2#'}

response = requests.post(url,payload)
```

They key point is here:

```
'Filter':'api_var1<eq>#var1# AND api_var2<eq>#var2#'
```

So if var1 = '1234' and var2 = '4321' I need it to be the equivalent of:

```
'Filter':'api_var1<eq>#1234# AND api_var2<eq>#4321#'
```

Comment: `'api_var1<eq>{} AND api_var2<eq>{}'.format(var1, var2)`? Or even `f'api_var1<eq>{var1} AND api_var2<eq>{var2}'` with python 3.6.

Comment: Is that format documented by the API provider? Is there an escape sequence? Is there a provision to avoid malicious data injection? (Consider what happens if `var1` contains a hash character.)

Comment: I'll pass that along to the developer, but yeah, that's the structure they dictate for filters, etc - they are probably expecting hardcoded values here, I wouldn't really know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want something like

```
'Filter':'api_var1<eq>#{0}# AND api_var2<eq>#{1}#'.format(var1, var2)}
```

or

```
'Filter':'api_var1<eq>#%s# AND api_var2<eq>#%s#' % (var1, var2)}
```

Comment: perfect, the first option works, thanks! I'd tried that already but was using '{0}' (with the single quotes) and was getting a syntax error.